# Generalize third-party classes with same getters without using reflection

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Here's a sample code:

```
class A {
    private Header header;
    private Data data;
}

class B {
    private Header header;
    private Data data;
}

class C {
    private Header header;
    private Data data;
}


class G {
    private Class messageType;
    private Header header;
    private Data data;

    public G(Object message) {
        messageType = message.getClass();   
        if (message instanceof A) {
            header = ((A) message).getHeader();
            data = ((A) message).getData();
        } else if (message instanceof B) {
            header = ((B) message).getHeader();
            data = ((B) message).getData();
        } else if (message instanceof C) {
            header = ((C) message).getHeader();
            data = ((C) message).getData();
        }
    }
}
```

Model classes `A`, `B` and `C` cannot be changed since they come from various libraries (note that the attributes are only simplified). 
So when I receive these instances, I'd like to treat them in a generic way that's why I created a `G` model class. Is there a way to assign attributes to `G` instance without `G` being closely tied-up to `A`, `B` and `C` without using reflection? It is not an option since it is really slow. Java 8 solution is ok.

Comment: No chance. Since they don't have a common superclass or implement the same interface, you have to either list them with ``instanceof`` like you're doing already or use reflection.

Comment: I can only offer you make a class with overriding of the get method: 
class G{
Data get(A a)
{ return a.getData();}
Data get(B b)
{ return b.getData();
Data get(C c)
{ return c.getData();}
}

Comment: how is reflection "real slow"? some libraries use it all the time without issues.

Comment: @eis we're dealing with a thousand messages in a second. no benchmarking is necessary for reflection approach.

Comment: yeah, I agree you'd notice it in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single Responsibility Principle: G is a message, not a message factory:

```
class G {
    private Class messageType;
    private Header header;
    private Data data;

    public G(Class<?> klass, Header header, Data data) {
        this.messageType = klass;
        this.header = header;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class GFactory {
    private Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, G>> mappings;

    public <T> void register(
             Class<T> klass,
             Function<T, Header> headerExtractor,
             Function<T, Data> dataExtractor) {
        Function<Object, T> cast = klass::cast;
        mappings.put(klass, cast.andThen(t ->
             new G(klass, headerExtractor.apply(t), dataExtractor.apply(t)))); 
    }

    public G createG(Object message) {
        return mappings.get(message.getClass()).apply(message);
    }

    private GFactory() {
        register(A.class, A::getHeader, A::getData);
    }
}
```

I also would say to not initialize the GFactory from within itself, but do that externally.

Comment: Nice! I can finally get rid of if-else conditions. Let me see if I can put the initialization of GFactory on spring context file.

Comment: Looks like a nice solution. Although I don't exactly understand what it is doing ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat: a solution, you can’t understand, wouldn’t make a good solution. But it’s not so hard to understand, if you focus on the `register(A.class, A::getHeader, A::getData)` line as the key to the solution. Of course, you have to add the lines for `B` and `C`.

Comment: Note that this solution needs additional work, if `A`, `B`, or `C` might have subclasses, which is outside the OP’s control.

Comment: @JulioD - I'm sorry, you use Spring on one hand but you're worried about reflection speed on the other? That doesn't make sense (unless you actually start reflection from scratch for every message)

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Spring only handles the initialization. It doesn't affect our manual handling of large volumes of messages.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

The only thing you can do: decouple the two **responsibilities** here. Meaning:

Instead of having **one** class that is responsible for retrieving attributes **and** doing this "instanceof" switching ... you could push that into two **different** classes.

Meaning: first you define some "data transfer class" that gives G what G needs, like

```
class Foo {
  Foo(String header, ...) { ...
  String getHeader() { ...
  ...
```

Then you move that "instanceof" switching into some sort of factory that has a method like:

```
class FooFactory {
  Foo makeFooFrom(Object message) { ...
```

And then G uses that FooFactory to acquire a Foo object for any incoming message.

But the thing is: without using reflection, the "implicit" complexity of having **different** fields in **independent** classes that happen to have the same **meaning** to you can't resolved.

The only "advantage" that my solution has: G doesn't need to know anything about A, B, C ... it just knows about the Foo class.

But of course, then FooFactory needs to know all these things. Most often, complexity is like water - you can make it go a different way, but you can't compress it or make it "disappear".

Comment: Thanks for this insight!